# Change Swipebox Caption from title attribute to Alt tag or Caption Tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox, caption

I am using a plugin call [Responsive Lightbox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/) and within it the Swipbox Layout. It works ok, but the caption does not appear as I wish. To have it appearing you need to include the **title attribute** on the link of the image. This is not a straight away thing for the bloggers on the site, as they are not very familiar with code and they already introduce the caption on image gallery that appears on the actual article. You can see an example here:

http://bicireview.com/2013/11/08/chaqueta-de-ciclismo-impermeable-como-elegir/

Note that if you click on the first picture you will see ***Prueba*** as a caption (it means Test in Spanish). But the actual caption should be ***Impermeable de ciclismo dhb – Hi Viz***.

If you go to any other picture I have not introduce the title attribute so, as you can see there is no caption.

I found the jquery open source code here and I will share it below. Do you know if there is a way to change the code so it takes the caption from what I already have?

Thank you very much in advance

```
  /*-------------

 @author       Constantin Saguin - @brutaldesign
 @link            http://csag.co
 @github        http://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox
 @version     1.2.1
 @license      MIT License

  -------------*/

;(function (window, document, $, undefined) {

$.swipebox = function(elem, options) {

    var defaults = {
        useCSS : true,
        initialIndexOnArray : 0,
        hideBarsDelay : 3000,
        videoMaxWidth : 1140,
        vimeoColor : 'CCCCCC',
        beforeOpen: null,
            afterClose: null
    },

    plugin = this,
    elements = [], // slides array [{href:'...', title:'...'}, ...],
    elem = elem,
    selector = elem.selector,
    $selector = $(selector),
    isTouch = document.createTouch !== undefined || ('ontouchstart' in window) || ('onmsgesturechange' in window) || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints,
    supportSVG = !!(window.SVGSVGElement),
    winWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width(),
    winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height(),
    html = '<div id="swipebox-overlay">\
            <div id="swipebox-slider"></div>\
            <div id="swipebox-caption"></div>\
            <div id="swipebox-action">\
                <a id="swipebox-close"></a>\
                <a id="swipebox-prev"></a>\
                <a id="swipebox-next"></a>\
            </div>\
    </div>';

    plugin.settings = {}

    plugin.init = function(){

        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if ($.isArray(elem)) {

            elements = elem;
            ui.target = $(window);
            ui.init(plugin.settings.initialIndexOnArray);

        }else{

            $selector.click(function(e){
                elements = [];
                var index , relType, relVal;

                if (!relVal) {
                    relType = 'rel';
                    relVal  = $(this).attr(relType);
                }

                if (relVal && relVal !== '' && relVal !== 'nofollow') {
                    $elem = $selector.filter('[' + relType + '="' + relVal + '"]');
                }else{
                    $elem = $(selector);
                }

                $elem.each(function(){

                    var title = null, href = null;

                    if( $(this).attr('title') )
                        title = $(this).attr('title');

                    if( $(this).attr('href') )
                        href = $(this).attr('href');

                    elements.push({
                        href: href,
                        title: title
                    });
                });

                index = $elem.index($(this));
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                ui.target = $(e.target);
                ui.init(index);
            });
        }
    }

    plugin.refresh = function() {
        if (!$.isArray(elem)) {
            ui.destroy();
            $elem = $(selector);
            ui.actions();
        }
    }

    var ui = {

        init : function(index){
            if (plugin.settings.beforeOpen) 
                plugin.settings.beforeOpen();
            this.target.trigger('swipebox-start');
            $.swipebox.isOpen = true;
            this.build();
            this.openSlide(index);
            this.openMedia(index);
            this.preloadMedia(index+1);
            this.preloadMedia(index-1);
        },

        build : function(){
            var $this = this;

            $('body').append(html);

            if($this.doCssTrans()){
                $('#swipebox-slider').css({
                    '-webkit-transition' : 'left 0.4s ease',
                    '-moz-transition' : 'left 0.4s ease',
                    '-o-transition' : 'left 0.4s ease',
                    '-khtml-transition' : 'left 0.4s ease',
                    'transition' : 'left 0.4s ease'
                });
                $('#swipebox-overlay').css({
                    '-webkit-transition' : 'opacity 1s ease',
                    '-moz-transition' : 'opacity 1s ease',
                    '-o-transition' : 'opacity 1s ease',
                    '-khtml-transition' : 'opacity 1s ease',
                    'transition' : 'opacity 1s ease'
                });
                $('#swipebox-action, #swipebox-caption').css({
                    '-webkit-transition' : '0.5s',
                    '-moz-transition' : '0.5s',
                    '-o-transition' : '0.5s',
                    '-khtml-transition' : '0.5s',
                    'transition' : '0.5s'
                });
            }


            if(supportSVG){
                var bg = $('#swipebox-action #swipebox-close').css('background-image');
                bg = bg.replace('png', 'svg');
                $('#swipebox-action #swipebox-prev,#swipebox-action #swipebox-next,#swipebox-action #swipebox-close').css({
                    'background-image' : bg
                });
            }

            $.each( elements,  function(){
                $('#swipebox-slider').append('<div class="slide"></div>');
            });

            $this.setDim();
            $this.actions();
            $this.keyboard();
            $this.gesture();
            $this.animBars();
            $this.resize();

        },

        setDim : function(){

            var width, height, sliderCss = {};

            if( "onorientationchange" in window ){

                window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
                    if( window.orientation == 0 ){
                        width = winWidth;
                        height = winHeight;
                    }else if( window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 ){
                        width = winHeight;
                        height = winWidth;
                    }
                }, false);


            }else{

                width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
                height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
            }

            sliderCss = {
                width : width,
                height : height
            }


            $('#swipebox-overlay').css(sliderCss);

        },

        resize : function (){
            var $this = this;

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $this.setDim();
            }).resize();
        },

        supportTransition : function() {
            var prefixes = 'transition WebkitTransition MozTransition OTransition msTransition KhtmlTransition'.split(' ');
            for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
                if(document.createElement('div').style[prefixes[i]] !== undefined) {
                    return prefixes[i];
                }
            }
            return false;
        },

        doCssTrans : function(){
            if(plugin.settings.useCSS && this.supportTransition() ){
                return true;
            }
        },

        gesture : function(){
            if ( isTouch ){
                var $this = this,
                distance = null,
                swipMinDistance = 10,
                startCoords = {},
                endCoords = {};
                var bars = $('#swipebox-caption, #swipebox-action');

                bars.addClass('visible-bars');
                $this.setTimeout();

                $('body').bind('touchstart', function(e){

                    $(this).addClass('touching');

                    endCoords = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
                        startCoords.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;

                    $('.touching').bind('touchmove',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                            endCoords = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];

                    });

                            return false;

                    }).bind('touchend',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                distance = endCoords.pageX - startCoords.pageX;

                    if( distance >= swipMinDistance ){

                        // swipeLeft
                        $this.getPrev();

                    }else if( distance <= - swipMinDistance ){

                        // swipeRight
                        $this.getNext();

                    }else{
                        // tap
                        if(!bars.hasClass('visible-bars')){
                        $this.showBars();
                        $this.setTimeout();
                    }else{
                        $this.clearTimeout();
                        $this.hideBars();
                    }

                    }   

                    $('.touching').off('touchmove').removeClass('touching');

                });

                    }
        },

        setTimeout: function(){
            if(plugin.settings.hideBarsDelay > 0){
                var $this = this;
                $this.clearTimeout();
                $this.timeout = window.setTimeout( function(){
                    $this.hideBars() },
                    plugin.settings.hideBarsDelay
                );
            }
        },

        clearTimeout: function(){   
            window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = null;
        },

        showBars : function(){
            var bars = $('#swipebox-caption, #swipebox-action');
            if(this.doCssTrans()){
                bars.addClass('visible-bars');
            }else{
                $('#swipebox-caption').animate({ top : 0 }, 500);
                $('#swipebox-action').animate({ bottom : 0 }, 500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    bars.addClass('visible-bars');
                }, 1000);
            }
        },

        hideBars : function(){
            var bars = $('#swipebox-caption, #swipebox-action');
            if(this.doCssTrans()){
                bars.removeClass('visible-bars');
            }else{
                $('#swipebox-caption').animate({ top : '-50px' }, 500);
                $('#swipebox-action').animate({ bottom : '-50px' }, 500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    bars.removeClass('visible-bars');
                }, 1000);
            }
        },

        animBars : function(){
            var $this = this;
            var bars = $('#swipebox-caption, #swipebox-action');

            bars.addClass('visible-bars');
            $this.setTimeout();

            $('#swipebox-slider').click(function(e){
                if(!bars.hasClass('visible-bars')){
                    $this.showBars();
                    $this.setTimeout();
                }
            });

            $('#swipebox-action').hover(function() {
                    $this.showBars();
                    bars.addClass('force-visible-bars');
                    $this.clearTimeout();

                },function() { 
                    bars.removeClass('force-visible-bars');
                    $this.setTimeout();

            });
        },

        keyboard : function(){
            var $this = this;
            $(window).bind('keyup', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (e.keyCode == 37){
                    $this.getPrev();
                }
                else if (e.keyCode==39){
                    $this.getNext();
                }
                else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    $this.closeSlide();
                }
            });
        },

        actions : function(){
            var $this = this;

            if( elements.length < 2 ){
                $('#swipebox-prev, #swipebox-next').hide();
            }else{
                $('#swipebox-prev').bind('click touchend', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $this.getPrev();
                    $this.setTimeout();
                });

                $('#swipebox-next').bind('click touchend', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $this.getNext();
                    $this.setTimeout();
                });
            }

            $('#swipebox-close').bind('click touchend', function(e){
                $this.closeSlide();
            });
        },

        setSlide : function (index, isFirst){
            isFirst = isFirst || false;

            var slider = $('#swipebox-slider');

            if(this.doCssTrans()){
                slider.css({ left : (-index*100)+'%' });
            }else{
                slider.animate({ left : (-index*100)+'%' });
            }

            $('#swipebox-slider .slide').removeClass('current');
            $('#swipebox-slider .slide').eq(index).addClass('current');
            this.setTitle(index);

            if( isFirst ){
                slider.fadeIn();
            }

            $('#swipebox-prev, #swipebox-next').removeClass('disabled');
            if(index == 0){
                $('#swipebox-prev').addClass('disabled');
            }else if( index == elements.length - 1 ){
                $('#swipebox-next').addClass('disabled');
            }
        },

        openSlide : function (index){
            $('html').addClass('swipebox');
            $(window).trigger('resize'); // fix scroll bar visibility on desktop
            this.setSlide(index, true);
        },

        preloadMedia : function (index){
            var $this = this, src = null;

            if( elements[index] !== undefined )
                src = elements[index].href;

            if( !$this.isVideo(src) ){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $this.openMedia(index);
                }, 1000);
            }else{
                $this.openMedia(index);
            }
        },

        openMedia : function (index){
            var $this = this, src = null;

            if( elements[index] !== undefined )
                src = elements[index].href;

            if(index < 0 || index >= elements.length){
                return false;
            }

            if( !$this.isVideo(src) ){
                $this.loadMedia(src, function(){
                    $('#swipebox-slider .slide').eq(index).html(this);
                });
            }else{
                $('#swipebox-slider .slide').eq(index).html($this.getVideo(src));
            }

        },

        setTitle : function (index, isFirst){
            var title = null;

            $('#swipebox-caption').empty();

            if( elements[index] !== undefined )
                title = elements[index].title;

            if(title){
                $('#swipebox-caption').append(title);
            }
        },

        isVideo : function (src){

            if( src ){
                if( 
                    src.match(/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/) 
                    || src.match(/vimeo\.com\/([0-9]*)/) 
                ){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        },

        getVideo : function(url){
            var iframe = '';
            var output = '';
            var youtubeUrl = url.match(/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
            var vimeoUrl = url.match(/vimeo\.com\/([0-9]*)/);
            if( youtubeUrl ){

                iframe = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+youtubeUrl[1]+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

            }else if(vimeoUrl){

                iframe = '<iframe width="560" height="315"  src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+vimeoUrl[1]+'?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color='+plugin.settings.vimeoColor+'" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';

            }

            return '<div class="swipebox-video-container" style="max-width:'+plugin.settings.videomaxWidth+'px"><div class="swipebox-video">'+iframe+'</div></div>';
        },

        loadMedia : function (src, callback){
            if( !this.isVideo(src) ){
                var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
                    callback.call(img);
                });

                img.attr('src',src);
            }   
        },

        getNext : function (){
            var $this = this;
            index = $('#swipebox-slider .slide').index($('#swipebox-slider .slide.current'));
            if(index+1 < elements.length){
                index++;
                $this.setSlide(index);
                $this.preloadMedia(index+1);
            }
            else{

                $('#swipebox-slider').addClass('rightSpring');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#swipebox-slider').removeClass('rightSpring');
                },500);
            }
        },

        getPrev : function (){
            index = $('#swipebox-slider .slide').index($('#swipebox-slider .slide.current'));
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
                this.setSlide(index);
                this.preloadMedia(index-1);
            }
            else{

                $('#swipebox-slider').addClass('leftSpring');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#swipebox-slider').removeClass('leftSpring');
                },500);
            }
        },


        closeSlide : function (){
            $('html').removeClass('swipebox');
            $(window).trigger('resize');
            this.destroy();
        },

        destroy : function(){
            $(window).unbind('keyup');
            $('body').unbind('touchstart');
            $('body').unbind('touchmove');
            $('body').unbind('touchend');
            $('#swipebox-slider').unbind();
            $('#swipebox-overlay').remove();
            if (!$.isArray(elem))
                elem.removeData('_swipebox');
            if ( this.target )
                this.target.trigger('swipebox-destroy');
            $.swipebox.isOpen = false;
            if (plugin.settings.afterClose) 
                plugin.settings.afterClose();
        }

    };

    plugin.init();

};

$.fn.swipebox = function(options){
    if (!$.data(this, "_swipebox")) {
        var swipebox = new $.swipebox(this, options);
        this.data('_swipebox', swipebox);
    }
    return this.data('_swipebox');
}
    }(window, document, jQuery));
```

Comment: because your a tag contain wrong title that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work. This does however.

```
if ( $( this ).find('img').attr( 'alt' ) ) {
  title = $( this ).find('img').attr( 'alt' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already gave up and my solution was here. Sorry for being so late in replying.

Answer (score 2):

You can change line 99 of Swipebox v1.2.9

In the previous version there are no curly brackets though

```
if ( $( this ).attr( 'title' ) ) {
  title = $( this ).attr( 'title' );
}
```

For:

```
if ( $( this ).attr( 'alt' ) ) {
  title = $( this ).attr( 'alt' );
}
```

In my case I used another hidden div next to the a element:

```
if ( $( this ).next( '.title' ).html() ) {
  title = $( this ).next( '.title' ).html();
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<a href = "image.jpg" class = "swipebox-img">Open lightbox</a>
<div class="title" style="display: none;"><p>The new title</p></div>
```

Comment: The second version here, by @MauroPesce **works very well,** even allowing `<a>` tags from the caption. This adds much to the Swipebox lightbox script. +1